# Tablayout and recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tabs, vertical-scrolling, indicator

I want to select tab while scrolling down recyclerview. I have used below method:

```
firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

I can get a position of the visible item. In my design, 2-3 items are showing on the single page.So for the 2nd or third item that is visible on the screen tabs will not move as item is already visible.

Is there any workaround for the same? How can i get the current position of the item?